# Не создаются категории товаров в woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

Есть плагин, который запускается по расписанию через wp cron и добавляет новые товары в woocommerce. Он использует класс `WC_API_Products`.

```
WC()->api->includes();
WC()->api->register_resources(new WC_API_Server('/'));
self::$wc_api = WC()->api->WC_API_Products;

// ...

$cat_args = array(
    'product_category' => array(
        'name' => $category_name,
        'parent' => $parent_id,
    )
);
$category = self::$wc_api->create_product_category($cat_args);
```

При создании новой категорий возникает ошибка:

> У вас недостаточно прав для создания категорий товара

Через админку категории создаются и на другом сайте эта ошибка не возникает. С чем может быть это связано?

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл решение - нужно было установить текущего пользователя:

```
$args = array(
    'role' => 'administrator',
    'number' => 1,
    'fields' => array('ID'),
);
$users = get_users($args);
wp_set_current_user($users[0]->ID);
```